# Using Floor and Int in a computation

Tags: int, fortran, floor

I am using a calculation to locate a base pixel. Seems to me that the two calculations for i and j are equivalent (i.e. i==j is always true) when I tried a few examples. Is this always true?

```
i = (int ((x - xmin) / a)) + 1
j = (floor ((x - xmin) / a)) + 1
```

In addition to the above, the following may give different result for i and j (i.e. there exist situations where i/=j).

```
i = (nint ((x - xmin) / a)) + 1
j = (ceiling ((x - xmin) / a)) + 1
```

Comment: Yes, It will be always true for the above statements.

Comment: Let `x = 1` (an integer), `xmin = 0.1`, `a = -0.2` (both reals) ...

Comment: Beware the integer arithmetics if `x`, `xmin`, and `a` are all integers!

Comment: The three variable will be reals in my case

Comment: if `a` is the size presumably `a=xmax-xmin` then all these things return only `1` or `2` ...  Seeing what I think you are trying to do, don't you think the (integer) pixel dimension should enter the calculation somewhere?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It will be always TRUE only in this scenario

When the value stored in ix with 'int' function, it will ignore the float values and just consider the whole number before the decimal point.
In case of Floor, it will convert to the nearest lower whole number.

The only difference is: In first case, floats are ignored, and in second case- the entire number is converted.

Ultimately, both the results are same. (Only in this scenario)
But its recommended to use right functions for right calculation.

Comment: That is not quite true! Consider negative numbers as argument!

Comment: Because I will always have xmin <= x, then x - xmin > 0

Comment: @Charles Next time, please add essential information as this limitation to the question! It quite changes the context...

Answer (score 1):

[`INT`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/INT.html) and [`FLOOR`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/FLOOR.html)  are different functions!

Consider this example:

```
program test
  print *,int(-1.2)
  print *,floor(-1.2)
end program
```

`INT` will return `-1`, `FLOOR` will return `-2`! So, no, these two statements are not the same!

To incorporate the changes to the question: [`NINT`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/NINT.html#NINT) rounds to the nearest integer, and returns an `integer`. [`CEILING`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CEILING.html#CEILING) is the opposite of `FLOOR` and will return the next largest integer.

Comment: My final result should be an integer. It must be equivalent to the pixel on the bottom left side of a square size a within which a coordinate resides.